# Converting integer Month to its name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, archive

Hi guys I'm currently doing a Blog Archive for my blog. I was able to call the list of blog by Year and Month but my problem is that my Month is displayed in integer. This image will show it 
[image]

I created a **ArchiveRepository**

```
public IQueryable<ArchiveListModel> AchiveList()
        {
            var ac = from Post in db.Posts
                     group Post by new { Post.DateTime.Year, Post.DateTime.Month }
                         into dategroup
                         select new ArchiveListModel()
                         {
                             AchiveYear = dategroup.Key.Year,
                             AchiveMonth = dategroup.Key.Month,
                             PostCount = dategroup.Count()
                         };

            return ac;
        }
```

I called it in my **Controller**

```
public ActionResult Archive()
        {
            var archivelst = repository.AchiveList().ToList();
            return View(archivelst);
        }
```

then show it in my **View**

```
<h2>Archives</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            AchiveYear
        </th>
        <th>
            AchiveMonth
        </th>
        <th>
            PostCount
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.AchiveYear
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.AchiveMonth
        </td>
        <td>
            @item.PostCount
        </td>      
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

How will I convert it to integer? T_T
**EDIT:**
I tried googling and found this answer

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(1);
```

But I don't know where to put it.. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it(`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(1);`) in View page

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @item.AchiveYear
    </td>
    <td>
        @System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(item.AchiveMonth)
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.PostCount
    </td>      
</tr>
}
```

Comment: Add `System.Globalization.` to that line. I updated my answer

Comment: Now that I've make it to work dude Im now facing another problem. How to add actionLink to anonymous type.. T_T I think I have to open another question for this.

Comment: I cant understand, but yes you open another question for explaning the scenerio...

Comment: I'm adding an actionlink to the list of archives that I generated to view the list of posts under it. But I'm having trouble with it since I'm calling anonymous type.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
AchiveMonth = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(dateGroup.Key.Month),
```

Comment: this line will give error. `linq to entities does not recognize the method ...`

Comment: You'll have to change the type of 'AchiveMonth' to string in your 'ArchiveListModel' class.

Comment: Problem is using function in linq query, also you right , if he want to use something like your suggestion after code modifiying, he can use.